# Why is the library built for armv7 even though I set -march=armv6?

Tags: gcc, arm, cross-compiling, x264

I'm trying to build libx264 for armv6, but what I get seems to be built for armv7. I'm using this configure line:

```
./configure --host=arm-linux-gnueabihf --enable-static --cross-prefix=${CCPREFIX} --prefix=... --extra-cflags='-march=armv6' --extra-ldflags='-march=armv6' --extra-asflags='-march=armv6'
```

which results in an output like this:

```
[...]
arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -Wno-maybe-uninitialized -Wshadow -O3 -ffast-math  -Wall -I. -I. -march=armv6 -std=gnu99 -D_GNU_SOURCE -fomit-frame-pointer -fno-tree-vectorize   -c -o common/opencl.o common/opencl.c
arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -Wno-maybe-uninitialized -Wshadow -O3 -ffast-math  -Wall -I. -I. -march=armv6 -std=gnu99 -D_GNU_SOURCE -fomit-frame-pointer -fno-tree-vectorize   -c -o encoder/slicetype-cl.o encoder/slicetype-cl.c
arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -I. -I. -march=armv6 -c -DSTACK_ALIGNMENT=4 -DHIGH_BIT_DEPTH=0 -DBIT_DEPTH=8 -o common/arm/cpu-a.o common/arm/cpu-a.S
[...]
```

now this is what I see:

```
$ readelf -A x264
Attribute Section: aeabi
File Attributes
  Tag_CPU_name: "7-A"
  Tag_CPU_arch: v7
  Tag_CPU_arch_profile: Application
  Tag_ARM_ISA_use: Yes
  Tag_THUMB_ISA_use: Thumb-2
  Tag_FP_arch: VFPv3
  Tag_Advanced_SIMD_arch: NEONv1
  Tag_ABI_PCS_wchar_t: 4
  Tag_ABI_FP_denormal: Needed
  Tag_ABI_FP_exceptions: Needed
  Tag_ABI_FP_number_model: IEEE 754
  Tag_ABI_align_needed: 8-byte
  Tag_ABI_enum_size: int
  Tag_ABI_HardFP_use: Deprecated
  Tag_ABI_VFP_args: VFP registers
  Tag_CPU_unaligned_access: v6
  Tag_DIV_use: Not allowed
```

also I see this:

```
$ readelf -A encoder/slicetype-cl.o
Attribute Section: aeabi
File Attributes
  Tag_CPU_name: "6"
  Tag_CPU_arch: v6
  Tag_ARM_ISA_use: Yes
  Tag_THUMB_ISA_use: Thumb-1
  Tag_FP_arch: VFPv2
  Tag_ABI_PCS_wchar_t: 4
  Tag_ABI_FP_number_model: Finite
  Tag_ABI_align_needed: 8-byte
  Tag_ABI_align_preserved: 8-byte, except leaf SP
  Tag_ABI_enum_size: int
  Tag_ABI_HardFP_use: Deprecated
  Tag_ABI_VFP_args: VFP registers
  Tag_ABI_optimization_goals: Aggressive Speed
  Tag_CPU_unaligned_access: v6
```

but:

```
$ readelf -A common/arm/cpu-a.o
Attribute Section: aeabi
File Attributes
  Tag_CPU_name: "7-A"
  Tag_CPU_arch: v7
  Tag_CPU_arch_profile: Application
  Tag_ARM_ISA_use: Yes
  Tag_THUMB_ISA_use: Thumb-2
  Tag_FP_arch: VFPv3
  Tag_Advanced_SIMD_arch: NEONv1
```

Can someone explain why those commands seem to output an armv6 binary once but an armv7 binary in the other case? May that be the reason why the resulting binary is marked as armv7?
Thank you for any explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is likely that `cpu-a.S` (it is used for CPU detection, right) is missing an `.object_arch` directive, to override the architecture automatically chosen by the assembler (due to the `.fpu neon` directive).

You should be able to fix this using:

```
.object_arch armv6
```

near the start of the file.

Comment: So I guess the assembler automatically chooses armv7 instead of armv6 right? This means that probably armv6 is not supported at all by that code. In fact I just found a --disable-asm option, which is probably to be used in this case. The result is now armv6. Thanks!